# Magento2: Console error - rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, http-error-500

rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods 500 Internal Server Error is Showing on Cart Page.

Shipping method is not showing.

Comment: re run setup:upgrade command, setup:di:compile and redeploy static contents

Comment: Ok, I will do and check. Thanks

Comment: I have tried got the same error.

Comment: check console log

Comment: /rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: you can go to var/report directory and check error files there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94336/discussion-between-magefms-and-masud-shaikh).

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: No, not found yet @ChiragPatel

Comment: @MasudShaikh Did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same error happening when selecting certain payment method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue.

1.rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods 500 Internal Server Error
2.rest/default/V1/carts/guest/estimate-shipping-methods 500 Internal Server Error

*At checkout page shipping methods were not displaying. This is issue with Magento_Amqp ,Magento_MysqlMq and Temando_Shipping modules.*

I solved this issue by updating composer. First run composer update command.

Run the command below and re-deploy magento.

```
composer update

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Hi, I had tried this but it's not working, getting same error.